# Chef-client run on specific date/time on windows nodes

Tags: chef-infra

I want to have chef poll the chef server at specific dates or times, as opposed to at a certain interval on a windows node. I do not want to use scheduled tasks if avoidable.

How would I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid scheduled tasks? I think that's the tool for doing exactly this on windows.

Comment: I would prefer to have something more akin to the way puppet does things. Possibly a scheduled task every 30 minutes but then have different recipes run based on Date/Time. That way I can listen more actively for updates while also maintaining control over how often the client actually applies a recipe.

Comment: That contradicts a bit with the idea of Desired State Config Management - because your desired state differs from run to run / time to time. You can override Chef's run list when starting chef-client, but not sure if this really helps (and your comment also doesn't match with your first question - maybe you want to elaborate on what your big picture is).

Comment: I think I need to reevaluate what I want to do and what with before I continue, thank you.